# Sharing SwiftData with iCloud users

Tags: swiftui, persistence, cloudkit, sharing, swift-data

has anyone figured out how to use swiftdata in SwiftUI with CloudKit to share data among other users and set permissions? Thank you!

I checked apple’s documentation along with the internet in general. I’m not sure it’s even supported…